# Build failure - mvn -U clean install

Tags: java, maven

I've rebuild my project using maven.I'm getting the below error. How to reslove the below error. Please advise me.

**Maven version:** Apache Maven 3.6.1

> > mvn -U clean install

Output:

[image]

How to resolve the error

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or some other obstruction?

Comment: Can you convert the screenshot of text back into normal text? As it is, it is too small to read.

Comment: From what I can tell it's failing to read https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/logging-parent/5/logging-parent-5.pom - but that file works fine for me, try again maybe or troubleshoot your connection to that site. Check disk isn't full, maybe update maven, 3.6.1 is from 2019-04-04